# How to get list of string values from enum when all values are stored in on database field

Tags: c#

Say I have the following enums which represents a combination of  properties that can be assigned to an object.

```
public enum ObjectFlags
    {
        None = 0,
        Red = 1 << 0,   // 1
        Square = 1 << 1,   // 2
        Small = 1 << 2,   // 4
        Fast = 1 << 3,   // 8
    }
```

I store any selected property  in a SQL database field called ObjectFlag:

Say I passed in Red and Small enums to the SaveOjectFlags method and
storethe integer combination using bitwise in a field .

```
 public ActionResult SaveOjectFlags(List<string> myflags)
```

{
     ObjectFlags = myFlags;
    foreach (var flag in ObjectFlags)
     {
    mydatabaseTable.ObjectFlag += (int) Enum.Parse(typeof (ObjectFlags), flag);
       _dbRepo.Save();
    }
}

Now I wish to get the values from my ObjectFlags field in my database and get the enums as a list of strings:

I have tried doing the following which didn’t quite work:

```
var test = (ObjectFlags)mydatabaseTable.ObjectFlag;
```

The values of the variable test  above  doesn't = a list of strings from the enum

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't quite work"? And what is `ObjectFlags` in your `foreach` loop? Note that if you call `ToString` on a flags enum - you do need to use the `[Flags]` attribute - you'll get a comma-separated list of names.

Comment: I made some updates to the question

Comment: That's still pretty unclear, with a method without braces, no obvious declaration of `ObjectFlags` as a variable (we can only see it as a type) and *still* no explanation of what "didn't quite work" means...

Comment: Made some edits. All Im trying to do is return a list of string values based on the single integer value using bitwise

Comment: Well what *does* `test` give? What happens if you call `ToString()` on it? Can you show a short but complete example? (You don't need a database to demonstrate this, after all...)

Comment: Y(ou are right. I just needed to add the flags attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278820/Optimized-Enum-ToString)

The solution is:

```
[Flags]
public enum ObjectFlags
{
    None = 0,
    Red = 1 << 0,   // 1
    Square = 1 << 1,   // 2
    Small = 1 << 2,   // 4
    Fast = 1 << 3,   // 8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was add the [Flags] attribute as Jon Skeet suggested